# Kdenlive composite effect not stretching

Tags: kdenlive

I am using Kdenlive to edit a school project and I need to use small amounts of a green-screen effect. I have seen several tutorials and understand how to do it, but the composite effect will not stretch. In every tutorial I have seen the composite starts large and is able to stretch, but when I do it it starts small and will not stretch. I cannot find any handles to stretch it with. I can use the glove to move it around, but not stretch it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Use the "Composite and Transform" transition instead.